# Entity that has multiple properties referencing same entity

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

I have a scenario where an entity needs to connect to another entity multiple times using different relationships.

```
class Binder
{
    //additional properties//

    Check Check {get; set;}
    List<Check> SubChecks {get; set;}
}

class Check
{
    //additional properties//

    Binder Binder {get;set;}
    List<Binder>? GroupBinders {get;set;}
}
```

Now naturally EF Core loses its mind as it cannot determine the relationship directions and ownership.

So i attempted to do something in OnModelCreating but i just cannot figure out the right combination for the life of me.

Use case is:

```
Binder can have multiple checks
But those Checks can have multiple binders
```

So essentially you end up with a big tree. Top of the tree is always a binder.

Comment: what about an intermediate entity BinderCheck ?

Comment: @jmvcollaborator how will that solve the problem and which relationship will it solve?

Comment: this "Binder can have multiple checks But those Checks can have multiple binders" looks totally a M:N relationship unless i am missing something

Comment: @jmvcollaborator There are two relationships in play here at the same time. A 1-M and a 1-1 relationship